# Makefile match rule based on variable in other file

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I want to create a makefile rule that will be matched only if variable was changed.

I have `Rules.make` that contains `KERNEL_VERSION=A0XX` variable.

In the end of the compilation I have `uImage` created, with `A0XX` string inside the binary.

I want to create a rule that will read the version from `uImage` (I am using 
**`strings uImage | grep A0`**)
And if `KERNEL_VERSION` variable is different, only then match the rule, otherwise do nothing.

Is that possible?

Comment: Makefile rules aren't **called**; they might be **matched**.  Perhaps that's part of your problem?

Comment: Guys, please don't spam. If you can't accept **rules running** or **rules called** you can push the 'edit' button on bottom of the comment, But please don't put garbage answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want can be achieved this way:

```
.PHONY: aux-rule var-changed
all: aux-rule;

cmd := strings uImage | grep "\bKERNEL_VERSION=A0XX\b"
check-var = $(if $(shell $(cmd)),,var-changed)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
aux-rule: $$(check-var)

var-changed:
    @echo Variable was changed
```

It consists of generating a prerequisite dynamically if the variable has changed.

Basically, by expanding expanding `check-var` as the prerequisite for the target `aux-rule`, the target `aux-rule` will depend on the prerequisite `var-changed` *only if* the variable `KERNEL_VERSION` in the `uImage` file has a value other than `A0XX`. Otherwise the target `aux-rule` will have *no prerequisites* at all, and therefore the recipe for `var-changed` won't be executed as a prerequisite for `aux-rule`.

In other words, if the variable changed, the rule will be expanded to

```
aux-rule: var-changed
```

otherwise, if the variable didn't change, it will be:

```
aux-rule:
```

Determining whether the variable `KERNEL_VERSION` in the `uImage` file has the value `A0XX` is based on the command `strings uImage | grep "\bKERNEL_VERSION=A0XX\b"`.

Comment: tnx :) So can please explain why _check-var_ is doubly expanded when it is a prerequisite for _aux-rule_?

Comment: That is for checking the variable in `uImage` exactly at the moment of matching the rule `aux-rule`. You would need to perform a *secondary expansion* of `check-var` if another rule in the same makefile could change the the variable in `uImage` before the `aux-rule` is matched. In the makefile above it is actually not necessary (it is just a minimal working example). That is, you can remove both the `.SECONDEXPANSION` target and simply replace `$$(check-var)` with `$(check-var)`.